# How to give padding to the place holder 'Select Date' for Angular material date picker to align to middle of input box

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Demo link for this issue, with css i tried

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-p9y9ju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
placeholder="          Select Date"
```

Or this.

```
.mat-input-element {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: @Dinesh hope this works for you. please let me know if anything required.